# Увеличить скорость проверки доступности серверов

Tags: c#

Имеется несколько компьютеров с 3g модемами, на них должен быть запущен apache(порт 8080). Как проверить что apache запущен на каждом из них. Visual studio 2013 c#. Вот так проверяю доступность серверов.

```
     WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://A.B.C.D:8080/");
     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
// failed
}
 response.Close();
```

Но когда проверяю список из 30 адресов то программа сильно зависает и долго проверяет. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Многопоточность не пробовали? вообще, тут вы вряд ли что сможете ускорить кроме как распаралелив запросы. т.к. скорость зависит не от вас, а от загруженности серверов и каналов связи. Устойчивости каналов связи, 3g не самый устойчивый канал, если вообще можно говорить о какой-то устойчивости

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте `async/await`. Он позволит легко распараллелить запросы, не нагружая при этом систему.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var addresses = new List<string>()
        {
            "http://ya.ru", "http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com"
        };

        var progress = new Progress<string>(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
        var tasks = addresses.Select(a => CheckAddress(a, progress)).ToArray();
        // вне консольного приложения стоит писать await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }

    private static async Task CheckAddress(string address, IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        // TODO: не забудьте добавить обработку ошибок
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
        progress.Report(string.Format("{0} - {1}", address, response.StatusCode));
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: await Task.WhenAll(tasks); Выдает ошибку: "Ошибка 1 Оператор await можно использовать только в методах с модификатором async. Попробуйте пометить этот метод модификатором async и изменить тип его возвращаемого значения на Task."

Comment: @AlexandrSamodurov ну так попробуйте пометить.