# Как распараллелить Ping?

Tags: c#

При обычном использовании Ping программа работает очень долго и зависает. Как можно распараллелить Ping?

Comment: Как понять "При обычно использовании Ping" ? Приведите пример вашего кода для начала.

Comment: Ping p = new Ping();
                      PingReply reply = p.Send("addres");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите мой ответ на один из ваших [предыдущих вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503708/106). Ситуация совершенно аналогичная, только вместо `WebRequest` и `GetResponseAsync()` используйте `Ping`, [`SendPingAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159414(v=vs.110).aspx). Это будет более разумным использованием ресурсов, см. ответы [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503721/) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491632/).

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var ipAddresses = new List<string>()
        {
            "1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2", "3.3.3.3"
        };

        var progress = new Progress<string>(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
        var tasks = ipAddresses.Select(a => PingAddress(a, progress)).ToArray();
        // вне консольного приложения стоит писать await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }

    private static async Task PingAddress(string ipAddress, IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        // TODO: не забудьте добавить обработку ошибок
        var ping = new Ping();
        PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(ipAddress);
        progress.Report(string.Format("{0} - {1}", ipAddress, reply.Status));
    }
}
```

Comment: `SendPingAsync(address)`  должна принимать IP, а не URL
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Когда начинает выполняться этот метод , то приложение зависает и не реагирует ни на какие действия, можно ли это исправить?

Comment: @koks_rs, ну значит добавить `Dns.Resolve(address).AddressList[0]`, и использовать IP адрес. Ну и не забыть на пустоту проверить массив адресов.

Comment: @AlexandrSamodurov, запустите содержимое метода `Main` в отдельной задаче.

Comment: Ip я уже получил, но все-равно программа перестает отвечать пока выполняется этот метод. Хотя метод возвращает нужный результат

Comment: @AlexandrSamodurov, `Task.Run(()=> { тут код из main});`,

Comment: А как быть не в консольном приложении?

Comment: Спасибо огромное всем за помощь. Все получилось

Comment: @AlexandrSamodurov прочитайте внимательнее комментарий в коде: *"вне консольного приложения стоит писать await Task.WhenAll(tasks)"*. Плюс вы уже уже справились в предыдущем вопросе.

Comment: @Alexis это немножко костыль :). Лучше дать async/await волю расползтись по коду, если есть возможность.

Comment: @koks_rs спасибо, поправил пример.