# Как выполнить массив Task[] в фоне?

Tags: c#, winforms, tpl

Имеется код:

```
var Tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (string el in OFD.FileNames)
{
    Tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => performFFT(Id, buffer)));
}

while (Tasks.Count > 0)
{
    int index = Task.WaitAny(Tasks.ToArray());
    Tasks.RemoveAt(index);
    progressBar.PerformStep();
}
```

Как выполнить все таски в фоне?

т.к. становится недоступной главная форма

Comment: какую версию .Net используете?

Comment: я использую версию .Net 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете .NET 4.5 и старше, то проще всего решить эту задачу через асинхронный код.

```
private async Task m()
{
    var Tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (string el in OFD.FileNames) {
        Tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => performFFT(Id, buffer)));
    }

    while (Tasks.Count > 0) {
        var task = await Task.WhenAny(Tasks.ToArray());
        Tasks.Remove(task);
        progressBar.PerformStep();
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне бы просто ещё сдвигать ползунок прогресса
    progressBar.PerformStep(); после каждого выполненного таска

Comment: @zakihatfild ну тогда используйте `WhenAny` в цикле, также как делали раньше.

Comment: @zakihatfild либо используйте [`Progress<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (этосчитается более каноничным с т.з. TAP). Его нужно передавать в метод `performFFT`, пример можно посмотреть [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503708/106).

Comment: что в using прописать
для async?

Comment: Нужно чтобы таски выполнялись параллельно. await разве не будет дожидаться выполнения каждого таска?

Comment: Исправил код, таски запускаются параллельно, после завершения каждого таска обновляется прогресс бар. Чтобы асинхронный код работал, проект должен использовать .NET 4.5 и старше, VS 2012 и старше. В using достаточно System.Threading.Tasks.

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой способ такой. Таски на самом деле *уже* начинают выполняться в тот момент, когда вы вызываете `Task.Run()` (если вам не нужны дополнительные параметры на запуске, это менее многословный способ запуска, нежели `Task.Factory.StartNew()`). Дальше мы лишь дожидаемся их выполнения.

```
var Tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (string el in OFD.FileNames)
{
    Tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => performFFT(Id, buffer)));
}

while (Tasks.Count > 0)
{
    int index = await Task.WhenAny(Tasks.ToArray());
    Tasks.RemoveAt(index);
    progressBar.PerformStep();
}
```

Однако более каноничным с т.з. паттерна TAP будет использование `Task.WhenAll()` и [`Progress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (он [запоминает](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/505fd18cebba3ec1.html) контекст, в котором был создан, и репорты выполняет в нем).

```
var Tasks = new List<Task>();
var progress = new Progress<int>(i => progressBar.PerformStep());

foreach (string el in OFD.FileNames)
{
    Tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => performFFT(Id, buffer, progress)));
}

await Task.WhenAll(Tasks);

...

private void performFFT(..., IProgress<int> progress)
{
    // делаем работу
    progress.Report(0); //параметр в вашем случае неважен 
}
```

Comment: Всмысле каноничным?
Есть разница?

Comment: Иии да, Ошибка: Оператор await можно использовать только в методах с модификатором async. Попробуйте пометить этот метод модификатором async и изменить тип его возвращаемого значения на Task.